# Using ClassTag with Variance

Tags: scala

I have a transfomer which is just a scala function, but needs ClassTag for interop with legacy code:

```
trait Transformer[F, T] extends (F => T) {
  implicit def cF: ClassTag[F]
  implicit def cT: ClassTag[T]

  /**
   * Append another transformer to this transformer
   */
  def >=>[U: ClassTag](f: Transformer[T, U]): Transformer[F, U] = Transformer(this andThen f)
}

/** Helper to view a function as a transformer */
object Transformer {
  def apply[F: ClassTag, T: ClassTag](f: F => T): Transformer[F, T] = new AbstractTransformer[F, T] {
    override def apply(x: F): T = f(x)
  }
}

abstract class AbstractTransformer[F, T](implicit override val cF: ClassTag[F], override val cT: ClassTag[T]) extends Transformer[F, T]
```

However, I would like to have the same variance in `T` and `F` as scala 
Function1 which is

```
trait Transformer[-F, +T] extends (F => T)
```

However this results in

> contravariant type F occurs in invariant position in type =>
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[F] of method cF    Transformer.scala
>
> covariant type T occurs in invariant position in type =>
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[T] of method cT    Transformer.scala

Can I solve this problem somehow?

Answer (score 2):

```
import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance
...
implicit def cF: ClassTag[F @uncheckedVariance]
implicit def cT: ClassTag[T @uncheckedVariance]
```

However, you need to be careful using this: there is a reason for the error! For example, consider

```
val t: Transformer[String, Object] = ...
val t1: Transformer[Object, String] = t // legal by variance
val c1 = t1.cF // the compiler thinks it's a ClassTag[Object], but really it's the ClassTag for String
val c2 = t1.cT // vice versa
```